# What should be the changes I have to make to make to link Heroku Node.js with Hostinger front end?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku

I have never deployed any web app ever. I have both domain name and hosting in Hostinger. I'm planning to host my node.js in Heroku and keep front end in Hostinger.

Can I get some suggestions on how to link my front end and back end?
Here is my backend index.js file

```js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const authRoute = require("./routes/auth");
const userRoute = require("./routes/users");
const postRoute = require("./routes/Posts");
const categoryRoute = require("./routes/categories");
const multer = require("multer");

dotenv.config();
app.use(express.json());

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL)
.then(console.log("connected to mongoDB"))
.catch((err) => console.log(err));

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, "images");
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, "Hello.jpeg");
    }
});

const upload = multer({storage:storage});
app.post("/api/upload", upload.single("file"), (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).json("File has been uploaded");
});

app.use("/api/auth", authRoute);
app.use("/api/users", userRoute);
app.use("/api/posts", postRoute);
app.use("/api/categories", categoryRoute);

app.listen("5000", () => {
    console.log("backend is running");
});
```

I am not getting any idea on how to connect this with my front end. Before posting it here, I searched for it before posting it here. I found that something I have to mention in package.json files and post addresses have to be changed, unfortunately I don't have much idea on that too.

UPDATE
I pushed my codes with github. Front end is running smooth but no response from backend. I am not able to fetch datas from MongoDb.

Answer (score -1):

I am sure you already figured this out. You just need use axios or fetch to get data from backend. Also use cors to prevent the error from transferring data between backend and frontend

Comment: Your answer should provide helpful information on the topic.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I have deployed app on heroku, but Node portion is not working. Only front end is running.